# How do I extract the height and width of an object from the matrix values in an SVG file?

Tags: javascript, php, svg

How do I determine the width and height of this object?  I would prefer to do it with PHP, but JavaScript is ok as well.

```
<g
     id="g1538">
    <path
       id="path1529"
       style="fill:#ff3fff;stroke-width:25;stroke-linejoin:round"
       d="m 1790.6137,1036.8231 a 499.63898,470.75812 0 0 1 -499.639,470.7581 499.63898,470.75812 0 0 1 -499.63895,-470.7581 499.63898,470.75812 0 0 1 499.63895,-470.7581 499.63898,470.75812 0 0 1 499.639,470.7581 z" />
    <g
       aria-label="TEST"
       id="text1533"
       style="font-size:500px;line-height:1.25;font-family:Arial;-inkscape-font-specification:'Arial, Normal';font-variant-ligatures:none">
      <path
         d="M 1406.173,964.62091 V 648.94708 h -117.9199 v -42.23633 h 283.6914 v 42.23633 h -118.4082 v 315.67383 z"
         id="path1541" />
      <path
         d="M 1621.505,964.62091 V 606.71075 h 258.7891 v 42.23633 h -211.4258 v 109.61914 h 197.998 v 41.99219 h -197.998 v 121.82617 h 219.7265 v 42.23633 z"
         id="path1543" />
      <path
         d="m 1937.9113,849.63068 44.6777,-3.90625 q 3.1738,26.85547 14.6484,44.18945 11.7188,17.08984 36.1328,27.83203 24.4141,10.49805 54.9317,10.49805 27.0996,0 47.8515,-8.05664 20.752,-8.05664 30.7618,-21.97266 10.2539,-14.16016 10.2539,-30.76172 0,-16.8457 -9.7657,-29.29687 -9.7656,-12.69532 -32.2265,-21.24024 -14.4043,-5.61523 -63.7207,-17.33398 -49.3164,-11.96289 -69.0918,-22.46094 -25.6348,-13.42773 -38.3301,-33.20312 -12.4512,-20.01954 -12.4512,-44.67774 0,-27.09961 15.3809,-50.53711 15.3808,-23.68164 44.9219,-35.88867 29.541,-12.20703 65.6738,-12.20703 39.7949,0 70.0684,12.93945 30.5175,12.69531 46.875,37.59766 16.3574,24.90234 17.5781,56.39648 l -45.4102,3.41797 q -3.6621,-33.93555 -24.9023,-51.26953 -20.9961,-17.33398 -62.2559,-17.33398 -42.9687,0 -62.7441,15.86914 -19.5313,15.625 -19.5313,37.84179 0,19.28711 13.916,31.73828 13.6719,12.45118 71.2891,25.63477 57.8613,12.93945 79.3457,22.70508 31.25,14.4043 46.1426,36.62109 14.8926,21.97266 14.8926,50.78125 0,28.56446 -16.3575,53.95508 -16.3574,25.14648 -47.1191,39.30664 -30.5176,13.91602 -68.8477,13.91602 -48.5839,0 -81.5429,-14.16016 -32.7149,-14.16016 -51.5137,-42.48047 -18.5547,-28.56445 -19.5312,-64.45312 z"
         id="path1545" />
      <path
         d="M 2378.5851,964.62091 V 648.94708 h -117.9199 v -42.23633 h 283.6914 v 42.23633 h -118.4082 v 315.67383 z"
         id="path1547" />
    </g>
  </g>
```

Comment: In javascript you can use getBBox() for this. Also I let you know that you have a group id="text1533" where you try to set the font-size, line-height, font-family and many more font related properties for a set of 4 paths. You can delete the style of that group.

Comment: The bounding box of a path can't be known until it is actually rendered. More precisely, the extremes of bezier curves can only be found numerically. So to solve this server-side, you need some rendering software: a headless browser, an SVG editor (inkscape has a commandline interface capable of solving this), or, as a last resort, a library specialized in computing bezier curves, elliptical arcs and the SVG path syntax.

Comment: As others have said, you will probably need to render the code first if you want to do it on the backend. Another question is, what are you actually trying to solve, and could this be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: you can use JavaScript to calculate the bounding box of the SVG element, which gives you the width and height